# crear PDF con fecha de Expiración

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

Me ha surgido una necesidad en crear un PDF con temporalidad, es decir, un PDF que tenga una expiración.

Si he creado PDF mediante **PHP** y **Javascript**, pero no se como puedo programar en el PDF que tenga una temporalidad, y una vez cumplida la temporalidad ya sea que:

1. Muestra una ventana indicando que se cumplió la temporalidad
2. No permita abrir el archivo PDF.
3. Se incruste una leyenda en el archivo PDF indicando la expiración.

El *PDF* que se debe crear puede ser mediante PHP ó Javascript.

Comment: Creo que un factor a tener en cuenta Alfonso es cual es la respuesta que esperas del usuario. Si quieres la temporalidad para que el usuario lea el PDF. O tambien puedes pensar en que si hay un botón con el cual generas el PDF quizás puedas luego de determinado tiempo deshabilitar ese boton por ende no podrán generar nuevamente el PDF.

Comment: @AgustinM. el PDF por si mismo debe tener la temporalidad, la temporalidad no la debe tener el sistema de software ( desactivar botones, quitar enlaces, etc). Si el PDF lo descargaste hace 1 semana o 4 meses, no importa, lo que importa es que este PDF tiene una temporalidad y debe hacer una acción ( una de las 3 que mencione en la pregunta ) y que se ejecute esa acción.

Comment: Tienes una tabla donde guardes la duración o la fecha de expiración del pdf? Creo que lo más simple sería comparar esa fecha con la actual y así decidir si mostrarle el pdf o sólo el mensaje que de el archivo ya expiró.

Comment: @Dan Gracias, por la respuesta, pero sabes algo, el PDF no podrá compararse con los datos de ninguna DB, es un PDF que podrás abrir en cualquier lugar; Dispositivo, Computadora, etc. Y cuando lo abras que detecte la fecha y ahi se ejecute la temporalidad.

Comment: @AlfonsoCarrasco Aparte que le impediría al usuario copiar el contenido del .PDF y guardarlo en otro archivo que no tenga ese bloqueo temporal

Comment: Es que no se puede agregar una fecha de expiración a los pdf simplemente porque no hace falta, pero para saber si ya caduco o no el archivo tendrías que verificar en otro lado (como en una bd) la fecha de expiración, y cuando el usuario haga la petición en su browser o celular hagas la verificación de la fecha (usando php) pero eso ya depende de la arquitectura de la webapp

Comment: @AlejandroRicotti Tienes razón no habia pensado en Guardarlo en otro Archivo, pero mira igual me doy con que le muestre la alerta ó un aviso dentro del PDF... como vez, tienes alguna idea?

Comment: @Dan Oye pero fíjate que no esta basado en ningún WeApp, es un PDF que se genera mediante un Script y su apertura no depende de la Web. Entiendo lo que me comentas con respecto a lo de la verificación de la BD pero eso aplica cuando quieras descargar el PDF... Ahora como hacerlo una vez que ya fue descargado el PDF...?

Comment: @AlfonsoCarrasco buscando en [pdf with expiration date + php](https://www.google.com.co/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=pdf+with+expiration+date+%2B+php) en Google, encontré varias entradas en Stack Overflow que simplemente dice que no es posible generar dicha funcionalidad; pero si deseas investigar un poco mas, consulta [JavaScript for Acrobat](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/javascript.html).

Comment: Los hostings suelen tener la opción de programar tareas. Si cuando creas un pdf le pones una fecha de expiración, y haces un script que calcule la fecha actual con la de expiración y si coincide que se borre. Si programas esa tarea para que la ejecute a diario tendrás lo que buscas

Answer (score 2):

Uno de los comentarios que añadiste a tu pregunta es fundamental a la hora de responder, y debería haber formado parte de la pregunta como tal:

> El PDF por si mismo debe tener la temporalidad, la temporalidad no la
>   debe tener el sistema de software ( desactivar botones, quitar
>   enlaces, etc). Si el PDF lo descargaste hace 1 semana o 4 meses, no
>   importa, lo que importa es que este PDF tiene una temporalidad y debe
>   hacer una acción ( una de las 3 que mencione en la pregunta ) y que se
>   ejecute esa acción.

**Respuesta:**

No exite en la especificación PDF ningún elemento que permita hacer lo que pides, puedes consultar la especificación (en Inglés) aquí:

[PDF Reference Document](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf)

De todo lo que pides hacer, el único punto medianamente posible es el primero:

> 1- Muestra una ventana indicando que se cumplió la temporalidad

Lo que necesitas hacer es encontrar una librería PHP que te permita manipular eventos Javascript dentro de un PDF. Existe entonces un evento que se llama OpenAction a nivel de documento donde podrías poner tu validación JavaScript y mostrar un mensaje con alert().

Vale notar que si el usuario utiliza un lector PDF que no soporta Javascript, o que lo tiene deshabilitado, el mensaje no se mostrará y tu requerimientos se vuelven 100% imposibles de lograr.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es, al momento de generar el *PDF* guardar el valor en una base de datos de tu preferencia. Luego de esto, estableces el tiempo que vaya a durar el *PDF* activo (Ya sea en horas, días, meses o años). Luego, en el código *PHP*, haces un condicional donde hagas una comparación entre la fecha de creación, con la fecha actual, y si sobrepasa el límite, que mande un mensaje por *JSON* o de tu preferencia, y que se visualice en la vista.

¿Como saber la fecha actual? Pues en *PHP* hay una función llamada:

```
date();
```

Comment: A primera vista parece una buena respuesta pero muy muy muy corta de código... ¿no podrías ampliarla?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster no, no es una buena respuesta, en los comentarios el autor dice explícitamente: " el PDF por si mismo debe tener la temporalidad,"